# Change XAMPP extension path

Tags: php, xampp

Inside my mac  with yosemite I would like to install the extension intl.
I have follow some tutorial and I think that the extension is installed.
If I write into console:

```
locate intl.so
```

I get:

```
/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/intl.so
/usr/local/php5-5.4.27-20140409-100559/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/intl.so
```

But if I check with:

```
php -m | grep intl
```

I get an empty string instead of `intl`

So I have checked inside my xampp configuration about extension and the `extension_dir` is:

```
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/
```

so I have tried to copy intl.so inside this folder or to create a link but always when I try to `print php -m | grep intl` I get always empty string.

I have added `extension=intl.so` inside `php.ini` file

My .bash_profile is:

```
export XAMPP_HOME="/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles"
export PATH="/Applications/XAMPP/bin/php:${PATH}"
export PATH="${PATH}:/Applications/XAMPP/bin"
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/alessandrominoccheri/Sites/trimalcione.com/lib/Cake/Console"
export PATH
```

How can I put intl.so inside my extension_dir?

Thanks

Comment: You need `extension=intl.so` in your `php.ini` file

Comment: I have added already inside php.ini file